# Opera web browser kerberos authentication with delegation support

Tags: windows, opera, kerberos

I'm using a LAN web site which relies on impersonation to be able to connect to a SQL Server machine (located on another machine in the domain). I'm not able to get it to authenticate properly using the Opera web browser whereas Chrome, Edge, and others work fine when testing.

**My scenario detail...**

> - CLIENT (Machine 1)
> - connects to ASP.NET application installed on an  IIS server (Machine 2).
> - The ASP.NET application is using the SqlConnection class to connect to SQL Server (Machine 3).

The 3 involved computers are members of the same domain and I'm logged onto the machine with a domain account.

It works with the Chrome web browser because I have configured this registry setting:

```
    [HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Policies\Google\Chrome] 
    "AuthNegotiateDelegateWhitelist"="*.MYDOMAIN.local"
```

(It also works with FireFox, IE and Edge when configured appropriately)

It does *not* work with the Opera web browser.

**The error is:**

```
    Login failed for user 'NT AUTHORITY\ANONYMOUS LOGON'
```

Does Opera support Windows delegation or some way to allow this integrated authentication to the web app?

If it does, I need help understanding how to config it accordingly as I'm not having any luck using the otherwise typical Chromium based settings that allow this to work.

Comment: What is the "slight configuration" you did in Chrome? As Opera is based on Chromium since version 15, the same settings should have the same effect there. If you don't like Firefox and Chrome, you may also try the Vivaldi browser (based on Chromium like Opera).

Comment: I also thought that the Opera configuration would be similar to what I had to do for Chrome... anyway, I added a registry entry for Chrome:
[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Policies\Google\Chrome]
"AuthNegotiateDelegateWhitelist"="*.MYDOMAIN.local".

Comment: ggo - Is the asp.net site using web.config with SQL connection string? Not sure if it'd be helpful or not understanding how you have your web.config file configured, but a thought I wanted to mention. Good luck getting your question reopened and finding the help you posted this that you need.

Comment: Thanks for the idea, but no, the asp.net site does not use web.config. I have created a test asp.net application to reproduce the problem, and the connection parameters to SQL Server are hard-coded. And it works with other browsers..